# Help figuring out GDPR and pseudonymisation

Tags: gdpr

I have server that needs to identify returning visits from users. I'm trying to figure out what I can do and whether I'm supposed to ask for consent from the user.

I don't care who the actual user, let's say I want to know the last date of his visit.

1. I know I can set a cookie, but I will have to ask for consent.
2. I thought about saving the ip + userAgent + additional data in a hashed way - pseudonymisation.
   my plan is to hash the ip but the ua + other data as the salt for the hash. that would be my key and the value is the date of the visit.
   that way I have no idea to know who the user is, or how to restore this data. I will be able to know that last visit only if the user sends a request again with the same ip,ua, etc...

Does that require consent from the user or just mentioning that in the privacy policy on my website?

3. I saw google is anonymizing ip by masking it. so if I'll do the same Im creating a record that is no longer matched with just 1 user, it can be matched to many (depending on the ip mask). Does that require consent? what mask is enough? 1 bit? 8 bits?

What is important to mention that the data I save for each user is not unique to him. with the example above I will get multiple users that have the same value stored for them, since they visited the same day. So again, I don't see a way anyone could track these users.

I've listed my options from the most accurate to the least. If there are other options I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Whether GDPR requires you to get consent from the user depends in part on whether you have another basis for the processing.  This in turn depends on the reason for your need to identify returning users.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on two closely related compliance issues, GDPR and ePrivacy. An analysis of the GDPR situation suggests that all of your alternatives involve processing of personal data, but that (depending on processing purpose) consent may not be required. However, ePrivacy most likely does require consent in your case, even when avoiding cookies.

**GDPR** is fairly flexible and straightforward. For compliance, you must have a legal basis. I recommend starting with these three questions:

1. **What is the purpose of processing?**

   Answering this question accurately is a necessary prerequisite for the other questions. The same data processed for different purposes can have different compliance obligations.
2. **What is the legal basis for this purpose?**

   Possible legal bases are enumerated in GDPR Art 6. The most important are:

   - consent
   - necessity for performance of a contract with the data subject
   - legal obligation per EU or member state law
   - legitimate interest

   In the context of online tracking, only consent (opt-in) or legitimate interest (opt-out) are likely to apply.

   Legitimate interest requires you to perform a balancing tests between these interests and the rights and freedoms of the affected data subject. Sometimes, implementing additional safeguards can tilt the balance in your favour.
3. **What is the minimum data necessary to achieve the purpose?**

   Per the GDPR's data minimization principle, you can only process personal data to the degree that it is necessary for a specific purpose. Collecting more data might require another legal basis, e.g. consent.

   If the processing purpose can be achieved with pseudonymized data, pseudonymization is mandatory and will not affect a legitimate interest balancing test.

It is important to note that pseudonymized data is still personal data because it still enables re-identification. If direct and indirect re-identification is impossible it can be considered anonymized data that no longer falls under the GDPR. However, anonymization is extremely difficult in practice, so this route should not be relied on to “escape” from GDPR compliance.

A couple of notes in this context:

- Google Analytics uses terms with different meaning than in the GDPR. E.g. GA clearly collects personal data (including identifying information), but the terms of service prohibit you from uploading PII. The `anonymize_ip` function that truncates IP addresses is likely just a pseudonymization mechanism that doesn't achieve anonymization, especially since the truncated IP address is combined with other information. But the use of this function is still mandatory due to the data minimization principle.
- Your proposed solution of hashing a user agent signature into a fingerprint is generally sensible since it makes the individual inputs unreadable. When processed for some purposes, this fingerprint might even be anonymous.

  However, your purpose is re-identification of visitors. Only the storage of seen fingerprints involves pseudonymized data, but generating and checking this fingerprint clearly involves processing of personal data. Thus, GDPR applies.

  GDPR does not prescribe a legal basis to be used for cookies or browser fingerprints, and there is an argument that cookies or re-identification (on the same site only) could fall under a legitimate interest. But read on.

The **ePrivacy directive** is famous for its cookie consent requirement. However, it is more broadly about privacy in electronic communications. While it has clear prescriptions, they don't actually apply directly. Instead, every EU member state has its own implementation of the directive. These laws differ in some details, so you must check the variant in your member state.

Traffic data is any data that is necessary for performing a transmission. For a website, this includes IP metadata such as IP addresses, or HTTP metadata such as headers and cookies. Any processing of traffic data that goes beyond what is necessary is allowed only when (a) the data was anonymized, or (b) the user has consented. As discussed above, true anonymization is difficult to impossible, at least in your use case. Important consequences:

- it makes no difference here whether your store an ID in a cookie or whether you use HTTP headers to fingerprint the browser
- in either case, consent is required

Especially with regards to purposes such as cookie-based analytics, we have the awkward situation that the processing itself may fall under a legitimate interest, yet ePrivacy mandates consent. There was an attempt to overhaul ePrivacy in time for the GDPR, but that effort hasn't made any progress since 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.
In my case the data mentioned above that I intend to hash is to detect the country origin of the visitor. the data I save as I said is hashed and can't be restored. value is the date. so I'll end up with bunch of hashes that store the same date for example '05/13/2020'. that is the only information saved for a visitor. so the re-identification just assigns him to a group of people, that I stored for them '05/13/2020'. don't see how that is possible to link it to a "natural person".

Comment: I don't think it's clear from question or your answer that OP can identify a natural person given their IP address and user agent string. So how does GDPR apply?

Comment: @dor272 If you are merely collecting aggregate statistics (e.g. count visitors from each country) then that is anonymous data and you don't need consent. But the process you describe is more like a browser fingerprint, which clearly is personal data within the scope of the GDPR, even if you can't directly identify a natural person from the fingerprint. I'm not sure how the date factors in to this process. If you can edit your question with more a detailed explanation (possibly as pseudocode) I can provide a better response.

Comment: @Lag You're interpreting “identifiable” too narrowly. While a browser fingerprint is not directly identifying, it can be used to match a natural person to a record, thus re-identifying the pseudonymous data. GDPR Art 11 discusses processing without identifying information: the GDPR still applies, but specific data subject rights don't, unless the data subject provides data necessary for re-identification. Recital 26 discusses the difference between pseudonymous and anonymous data: it's still personal data if it can be re-identified with additional information or if a person can be singled out.

Comment: " While a browser fingerprint is not directly identifying, it can be used to match a natural person to a record" - by what means?

Comment: @Lag By comparing fingerprints of visitors to stored fingerprints. Depending on the number of visitors and bits of information in the fingerprint, unique re-identification is possible with non-negligible probability. Ad networks likely use such techniques to stitch sessions into larger profiles even when cookies are disabled. OP's actual use case is likely more benign, but they haven't provided enough info.

Comment: Right, so it isn't necessarily the case that a browser fingerprint is personal data (particularly if that's the only data), it depends on the circumstances. What other data OP has. What method OP is likely to use or could use to stitch it together. That is all I'm driving at.

Comment: @Lag
@amon
I show each visitor random value from a finite group lets say a visitor will be shown one of the following values `1,2,3`.
to provide consistent UX I need to know what was shown to who, meaning group visitors into groups, not caring about identifying a specific person or tracking any further. what are my options here?

Comment: @dor272 That potentially sounds like a task for a functional cookie, for which no consent is required.

Comment: @amon does the same goes if I choose to save the data as I mentioned before (for a limited time 7-30 days)?
Thanks for you help

Comment: @dor272 You're still providing far too little context, and these comments are not a very productive medium for extended back and forth. Whether storing the data for some time is OK depends on whether that is necessary for some purpose. What kind of UX settings are you saving? Is this for like a dark mode that the visitor can toggle? Then cookies are not a problem, and don't need consent. Is this for an A/B test? Those are not strictly necessary, but you only need one or two bits of information to assign visitors to a group, which would likely be anonymous data.

Comment: @amon
A/B testing. there's possibility to show each visitor different content. therefore, in order to provide a consistent content for each visitor I want to know what I showed him

Comment: So saving a cookie might be better since the information saved there is anonymous and relates the visitor to a group? while I can still aggregate pseudonymized for analytics, but not to save each record?
The end goal is to have A/B Testing while consistent with the UX: (meaning I want a visitor to be shown the same content as it was shown at the first time - in order to keep analytics right).
Any way that can be achieved with out asking for consent? This is a service I intend to provide so I'll be doing it for other websites as a 3rd party.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> Does that require consent from the user or just mentioning that in the privacy policy on my website?

Apparently neither.

Article 4(1) defines the concept of *personal data*, and recital 26 of the [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679) explains that "*[p]ersonal data which have undergone pseudonymisation, which could be attributed to a natural person by
the use of additional information should be considered to be information on an identifiable natural person*".

Accordingly, your data system seems to fall outside the scope of the GDPR insofar as your procedure precludes the possibility of identifying a natural person. Item 2 in your post and your remark that "*the data [you] save for each user is not unique to him*" suggest that that is the case. Therefore, there is no need for users' consent or awareness.

Comment: If the data has been successfully pseudonymized, further processing of pseudonymized data would fall outside of the GDPR. But the pseudonymization process itself does involve personal data, thus requiring a legal basis. And regardless of whether this is personal data, ePrivacy still applies when processing traffic data – this possibly requires consent.

Comment: @amon Your remark on ePrivacy is something the OP should ponder. I am just not knowledgeable of it to say whether or not it is worth to spend nearly as many resources as companies are devoting to the GDPR mess. As for your point on pseudonymization, the issue is not whether the process *involves* personal data, but whether the system *stores* it. See recital 15 ("*[t]he protection should apply to the processing of personal data [...] if the personal data are contained or are intended to be contained in a filing system*"). Per OP's 2nd-to-last paragraph, he is not really keeping personal data.

Comment: Thanks @IñakiViggers. so as far I can understand from your answer option 2 is good enough to not ask for consent.
What about option 1? all cookies ask for consent and opt in form or since the data I store on the cookie  is not unique to any specific user I can set that cookie with out asking the user?
Thanks again.

Comment: @dor272 Option 2 is safer from the GDPR standpoint than option 1 because cookie identifiers are considered *online identifiers* that can be associated to a natural person. See recital 30. Thus, with option 1 you not only would need user's consent, but it might also invite GDPR scrutiny notwithstanding your knowledge that such cookie is not uniquely traceable to a specific user. By contrast, hashing seems much, much harder to reverse [than restoring data under a cookie approach] and does not require user's consent.